# Does Python allow to parse a module and return all the functions/classes in it?

Tags: python

I am curious if there is a way, beyond the parsing of the py file as text file, to retrieve what is actually inside the module.

For example; if I import a module, and want to know what the module contain, and its usage (parameters needed, return types and so on), is there a way to do this directly through Python, or I have to actually load the file, like I would do for a text file, and parse it manually?

I have plenty of modules that I would like to document, and something like this would save me time to go trough each module and check them one by one.

Comment: Lazy partial solution: `import some_module; print dir(some_module)`

Comment: Trying it now, thanks

Comment: Also have a look at this: https://wiki.python.org/moin/DocumentationTools

Answer (score 1):

You can use ast to properly parse all the module:

```
import inspect
import importlib
import ast


class ParseMod(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_FuncDef(self,node):
        print("In func")
        print(node.name)
        print(node.args)
        self.generic_visit(node)

    def visit_ClassDef(self,node):
        print("in class")
        print(node.name)
        for n in node.body:
            print(n.name)
        self.generic_visit(node)

    def visit_Call(self, node):
        print("In call")
        print(node.func.id)
        print([ast.literal_eval(arg) for arg in node.args])
        self.generic_visit(node)


mod = "test2"
mod = importlib.import_module(mod)
p = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(mod))

par = ParseMod()

par.visit(p)
```

Input:

```
class Foobar(object):
    def func(self):
        return "func"


class Bar(object):
    def func2(self):
        return  "func2"

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2
        self.z = 3
    def func_foo(self):
        return "func_foo"


def some_func(a,b):
    """
    :param a: int
    :param b: int
    :return: int
    """
    return a,b

some_func(1,2)
```

Output:

```
in class
Foobar
func
in class
Bar
func2
in class
Foo
__init__
func_foo
In call
some_func
[1, 2]
```

There is a full list of all the available attributes and an explanation of each in the [greentreesnakes](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/nodes.html#Attribute) docs.

If you just want to collect the function and class nodes:

```
import inspect
import importlib
import ast
mod = "test"
mod = importlib.import_module(mod)
p = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(mod))



classes = [node for node in p.body if isinstance(node, ast.ClassDef)]
funcs = [node for node in p.body if isinstance(node, ast.FunctionDef)]

print(classes)
print(funcs)
[<_ast.ClassDef object at 0x7f9bc7884190>, <_ast.ClassDef object at 0x7f9bc7884350>, <_ast.ClassDef object at 0x7f9bc7884510>]    
[<_ast.FunctionDef object at 0x7f89d3377c50>]
```

Then extract what you want from each:

```
for f in funcs:
    print(f.name)
    print([a.id for a in  f.args.args])
    print(ast.get_docstring(f))

some_func
['a', 'b']
:param a: int
:param b: int
:return: int
```

There are a couple more example usages [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199328/how-can-i-find-python-methods-without-return-statements/30200033#30200033)  and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30037326/how-to-textually-find-an-imported-name-in-a-module/30037842#30037842)

Comment: Much appreciated Padraic! This is very useful

Comment: @newbiez, no worries, it is hard to provide a more complete example as there are limitless ways to get data but ast is a very powerful tool when dealing with the source. I will add a few links to some other answers of mine  that get various output

Comment: Indeed; you went the extra mile to show the concept, I appreciate it, since I am a beginner at Python. Thanks!

Comment: @newbiez, no prob, I added a couple of links to answers using ast for different purposes

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of strings corresponding to every member of a module using the `dir` method:

```
import some_module
print dir(some_module)
```

This will get you all the classes and functions of the module, with two drawbacks:

- it *also* gives you members that aren't classes or functions. For example, `dir(Tkinter)` contains `VERTICAL` and `SUNKEN` and `OFF` and `INSERT`, which are all just regular strings.
- if the module contains any code at the file level, then that code will be executed. Generally not a big deal, but if you're trying to inspect a lot of modules, the time lost can pile up.

Comment: Tanks Kevin; these 2 issues may be bothersome; So far the few modules that I tried, returned what I needed, but I need more time to investigate

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use [`inspect.getmembers()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html#inspect.getmembers) to introspect the contents of the module:

```
import types
import inspect
import mymodule

# find classes, shove them in a {'name':object} dict
is_class = lambda x: isinstance(x, type)
classes = dict(inspect.getmembers(mymodule, predicate=is_class))

# find functions, shove them in a {'name':object} dict
is_func = lambda x: isinstance(x, (types.FunctionType, types.BuiltinFunctionType))
functions = dict(inspect.getmembers(mymodule, predicate=is_func))

# etc...
```

It sounds like what you're really looking for is a tool for automatically generating API documentation, [of which there are several](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DocumentationTools).

Comment: Thanks Ali; documentation automation is one of the purposes; I was also curious to know how to introspect in python modules.