# Regex to catch code that uses private members in python, unless its a function def

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I'm trying to write a regex to catch any use of private members in python, with the exception of function names.

For example, the following should return true:

```
a = __something__
b.__something()
__bla = 5
a[__bla__]
... etc etc
```

But the following should return false:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    ....
```

(because it has the "def" before it)

I wrote this expression:

```
regexp = re.compile(r'(?!def\s)[^a-zA-Z^_\s]__[a-zA-Z]')
```

And it works for most cases, but for some reason it always return false if there's a space before the private, eg this will not return true:

```
regexp.search("something = __private")
```

What am I doing wrong here? the "(?!def\s)" should not match if have "def " before it, and I handle spaces before the two underscores, eg inside "[^a-zA-Z^_\s]". so why isn't it working?

EDIT:

While the accepted answer is correct for regex, I recommend looking at Padraic Cunningham's answer for a better solution using ast.
Thanks,

Comment: You just need to write a python parser for this. I don't think you'll ever get it right using regex.

Comment: Which if your interested in this site has a very nice tutorial. http://jayconrod.com/posts/37/a-simple-interpreter-from-scratch-in-python-part-1

Comment: You should use ast, a regex is almost certainly going to file at some stage

Comment: `__something__` isn't private. Do you really want to flag code like `super(Class, self).__init__()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try :

```
(?<!def\s)(\b__[a-zA-Z])
```

[Example](http://pythex.org/?regex=%28%3F%3C!def%5Cs%29%28%5Cb__[a-zA-Z]%29&test_string=a%20%3D%20__something__%0Ab.__something%28%29%0A__bla%20%3D%205%0Aa[__bla__]%0A...%20etc%20etc%0Aa__stuff%0Adef%20__unicode__%28self%29%3A%0Asomething%20%3D%20__private&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

[source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Good answer, but it still catches things like "a__stuff". I added "\b" before the '__' and now it works perfectly. Thanks :)

Comment: I think its a good practice for future seekers, but totally up to you. PS notice that with the \b it also catch it inside strings, but for my case its ok.

Answer (score 1):

Using [ast.NodeVisitor](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.NodeVisitor) it is very easy to get the attributes and a lot more reliable than a regex:

```
import inspect
import importlib
import ast

class FindAttr(ast.NodeVisitor):
    def visit_Attribute(self, node):
        print(node.attr)


mod = "test"
mod = importlib.import_module(mod)
p = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(mod))

f = FindAttr()
f.visit(p)
```

test.py:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__foo = "foo"

    def meth1(self):
        self.bar = "bar"

    def meth2(self):
        self.__foobar = "foobar"


    def meth3(self):
        self.blah = "foobar"
        return self.blah
```

Output:

```
In [7]: mod = "test"

In [8]: mod = importlib.import_module(mod)

In [9]: p = ast.parse(inspect.getsource(mod))

In [10]: f = FindAttr()

In [11]: f.visit(p)
__foo
bar
__foobar
blah
```

All you need to so is check `if node.attr.startswith("__")` etc.. You can visit any nodes you like, FunctionDef, ClassDef like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30199328/how-can-i-find-python-methods-without-return-statements/30200033#30200033), there is a comprehensive list of all the nodes in the [greentreesnakes](https://greentreesnakes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/nodes.html) docs and their attributes.

Comment: Your simple example convinced me to try out ast and it turned out great. It really is super easy to use and results are much more reliable. I already accepted the other answer (and also this question is about regex) but this is definitely a better solution for most cases. Thanks!

Comment: @Ness, no worries, yes it is really easy to use and more importantly a reliable way to parse.